# Woocommerce: Complex query in pre_get_posts

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, loop, filters, pre-get-posts

I want to add a complex filtering when getting my products.

- I have products where some of them are linked to a custom post type.
- This custom post type has a repeater field.
- Depending on a cookie, I should only get products that have that value in this repeater field

I know I can use:

```php
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'fwp_archive_per_page' );
```

I know i can set extra meta query like this:

```php
$query->set( 'meta_query', array(
    'relation'    => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'   => 'xxx',
            'value'     => 'xxx'
        )
));
```

But this is more complex as I should do a query on every product ID to check if the value exists in the repeater field from the related custom post type.

Anyone has a clue how to do this?
Or is there another way around to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I have complex querie to do,
I often use a prequery to get the good post_ids.
Then I pass this list of post_ids to my main query via the `post__in` [parameter of WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters).

```php
$meta_key = 'RepeaterName_%_FieldName';
$meta_value = 'MyCustomValue';

global $wpdb;
$post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
        SELECT      pm.post_id
        FROM        $wpdb->postmeta pm
        WHERE       pm.meta_key LIKE %s 
        AND         pm.meta_value = %s
    ",
    $meta_key, 
    $meta_value, 
) ); 
// Or with another custom $wpdb request 
// https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/
```

Then we add `$post_ids` to main query

```php
if ( !empty( $post_ids ) ) {
    $post__in = $query->get('post__in');
    if ( empty( $post_in ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post__in', $post_ids );
    } else {
        $query->set( 'post__in', array_intersect( $post_ids, $post__in ) )
    }
}
```

All this code must be placed in the `pre_get_posts` filter.
I hope that the response is up to your expectations.